# Plotting several 2d curves (with different colors) in a 3d graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, 3d

I'm trying to reproduce 3D plots with several 2d curves, like in [Plotting several 2D functions in a 3D graph](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/2d-functions-in-3d/). The end result looks like this:

[image: myplot]

The questions are:

1. I would like to change X labels (from 0-250 to 32-311);
2. Z labels are should be 1,2,3,5,...,10;
3. some curves doesn't starts on 0, so that the curves are tilted;
4. I would like to connect the onset, maximum and ending values among the curves in the X plane; and finally
5. If possible, choose the color of each curve.

Here is my code with some dummy data:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread{
        logger1 logger2 logger3 logger5 logger6 logger7 logger8 logger9 logger10
        1.04    33.89   2.3     3.19    0.01    134.57  0.58    0.2     99.5
        1.04    39.82   2.48    4.22    0       142.46  0.5     0.14    105.36
        1.04    46.34   2.38    2.61    0.27    145.42  0.71    0.61    109.83
        1.06    48.67   2.35    3.21    0.23    148.91  0.52    0.48    113.52
        1.15    52.63   2.31    3.26    0.03    152.23  0.72    0.27    118.07
        1.19    57.98   2.32    3.19    0       156.89  0.46    0.25    124
        1.02    59.51   2.39    3.24    0.15    158.96  0.35    0.25    125.97
        1.01    62.61   2.38    3.27    0.16    161.51  0.59    0.3     128.89
        1.07    64.75   2.4     3.17    0.18    162.86  0.78    0.46    130.14
        1.09    66.48   2.35    3.23    0.01    164.62  0.56    0.28    131.55
        1.21    69.16   2.35    3.24    0.04    167.08  0.57    0.28    134.21
        1.12    70.52   2.36    3.25    0       167.92  0.42    0.1     134.95
        1.21    72.26   2.39    3.98    0.12    171.72  0.71    0.4     139.06
        0.99    74.29   2.33    3.35    0.04    175.4   0.58    0.28    141.23
        0.98    75.08   2.3     3.06    0.07    175.79  0.4     0.53    141.31
        0.97    75.31   2.23    3.1     0.05    176.28  0.35    0.33    141.42
        0.94    74.85   2.2     2.99    0.04    176.01  0.44    0.24    141.35
        1       75.06   2.33    3.22    0.38    176.6   0.78    0.79    142.13
        1.04    75.46   2.24    3.11    0.23    176.59  0.58    0.45    141.92
        1.13    75.91   2.24    3.17    0.37    176.35  0.49    0.52    142.57
        1.07    75.17   2.13    2.93    0.18    175.35  0.52    0.37    141.51
        1.1     75.16   2.23    3.12    0.36    174.8   0.4     0.37    140.83
        1.14    77.29   2.35    3.3     0.27    175.37  0.65    0.55    141.93
        1.03    75.24   2.46    3.31    0       175.2   0.48    0.34    142.02
        1.2     78.83   2.19    3.09    0.18    175.81  0.54    0.4     142.99
        0.95    81.1    2.43    4.03    0.2     179.43  0.38    0.37    146.77
        1.1     81.94   2.41    3.26    0.07    180.02  0.49    0.5     146.72
        1.07    82.88   2.33    3.18    0.03    180.69  0.47    0.24    146.95
        1.1     89.25   2.35    3.2     0.07    187.26  0.55    0.32    151.91
        1.01    90.72   2.45    3.25    0.22    187.8   0.48    0.29    152.95
        1.05    93.72   2.32    3.48    0.18    190.84  0.66    0.31    155.68
        10.09   103.3   2.52    4.38    0.06    196.2   0.46    0.36    161.86
        6.41    105.08  2.42    2.99    0       197.89  1.01    0.25    163.24
        7.48    109.4   2.35    3.66    0.01    202.16  0.84    0.28    167.59
        7.09    116.85  2.44    3.99    0.05    210.24  0.47    0.8     171.93
        4.93    120.31  2.53    2.8     0.06    213.24  0.44    0.34    173.9
        2.44    122.82  2.53    3.32    0.03    216.29  0.53    0.23    175.44
        0.48    124.8   2.33    3.19    0.07    217.75  0.83    0.37    177.02
        0.98    127.75  2.49    3.43    0.06    222.64  0.55    0.39    179.72
        1.17    130.53  2.35    3.18    0.05    224.79  0.56    0.29    181.21
        1.04    133.33  2.21    3.7     0       228     0.66    0.48    182.96
        1.09    136.93  2.32    3.04    0.07    231.08  0.46    0.44    185.99
        1.08    139.51  2.42    2.87    0       233.2   0.41    0.13    186.95
        1.12    142.39  2.24    3.11    0       236.51  0.68    0.27    188.07
        0.96    145.84  2.15    3       0.07    239.89  0.72    0.34    189.44
        7.26    150.55  2.26    3.13    0       244.91  0.76    0.15    193.05
        19      156.77  2.3     3.62    0.13    252.07  1.09    0.49    196.24
        24.76   162.59  2.27    7.59    0.28    256.2   0.16    0.23    198.43
        30.8    169.09  2.42    12.26   0.07    261.25  0.46    0.65    200.97
        36.49   175.78  2.16    19.28   0       268.86  0.39    0.6     205.38
        46.56   187     2.56    31.82   0       281.19  0.4     1.15    213.23
        52.32   192.39  2.54    36.27   0       284.88  0.48    0.25    213.33
        60.69   200.95  2.51    44.46   0       293.09  0.63    0.42    216.23
        66.62   206.93  2.19    49.6    0.1     298.31  0.68    0.5     216.95
        76.83   217.2   2.28    59.9    0.08    309.94  0.59    0.38    221.61
        83.8    224.78  2.42    66.16   0       315.07  0.42    0.18    224.75
        89.88   231.06  2.31    71.7    0.05    320.66  0.65    0.31    228.32
        95.05   236.6   2.21    76.46   0.06    325.77  0.65    0.48    232.09
        100.91  242.75  6.13    81.6    0.06    331.23  0.68    0.46    237.2
        105.79  247.85  9.7     86.78   0.04    337.07  0.52    0.25    241.83
        111.07  253.96  13.96   91.13   0.09    342.27  0.76    0.46    248.13
        115.87  259.16  17.23   95.22   0.12    347.03  0.85    0.65    252.64
        121.45  265.19  20.33   100.34  0.34    353.11  0.78    0.47    257.69
        124.94  269.96  23.12   104.2   0.13    357.55  0.79    0.5     262.48
        132.65  277.22  26.44   110.57  1.58    364.74  1.09    0.17    268.7
        139.83  284.11  30.18   115.76  7.07    371.3   1.04    2.04    274.64
        143.19  291.74  35.54   121.89  9.22    379.72  0.6     0.39    283.49
        147.56  297.5   39.42   126.47  15.37   385.13  0.68    4.28    289.41
        152.5   303.81  43.2    131.42  19.48   391.04  0.69    10.7    295.63
        156.07  308.78  47.41   135.41  23.36   396.29  3.74    15.49   301.23
        160.26  314.27  51.31   139.93  26.62   401.58  6.57    20.08   307.05
        165.22  321.46  56.01   145.29  29.61   407.4   9.83    23.81   314.71
        169.3   326.5   60.22   150.31  33.48   412.99  15.54   30.42   320.69
        173.4   331.8   65.78   154.57  38.48   418.08  18.84   35.76   326.14
        176.62  336.59  70.23   158.28  41.41   422.38  22.09   39.18   331.57
        180.56  341.49  75.32   162.76  45.36   427.49  25.74   44.47   337.27
        185.19  348.33  82.82   167.88  47.89   433.3   29.25   49.51   345.45
        189.16  353.51  86.51   172.41  51.18   438.09  33.51   51.94   350.32
        192.3   356.9   90.2    175.23  54.97   440.71  36.66   56.42   354.57
        197.07  362.8   95.19   181.59  60.2    447.24  44.88   61.4    360.87
        200.26  367.21  100.86  184.61  63.27   450.31  45.54   66.13   366.12
        206.44  374.39  108.42  192.36  68.55   458.13  53.1    72      374.58
        211     380.06  114.94  196.98  74.34   462.88  56.56   78.03   380.93
        218.52  388.48  122.12  204.86  78.96   470.05  60.99   83.15   389.71
        222.6   393.14  130.06  210.16  85.74   475.87  67.26   90.15   396.27
        229.26  401.11  138.22  217.3   91.92   482.86  72.75   96.93   405.35
        233.61  406.03  145.25  222.65  96.74   488.17  76.88   102.73  411.29
        238.74  410.74  150.47  227.68  102.14  493.35  81.5    107.96  416.78
        242.82  416.43  157.08  234.1   108.93  500.07  87.9    114.92  423.07
        248.89  422.84  165.3   242.24  115.27  507.92  93.92   122.05  430.88
        253.41  428.29  170.38  246.97  120.23  512.91  98.2    126.97  436.32
        260.5   435.37  178.81  255.85  126.99  522.15  104.62  134.18  444.96
        270.44  446.25  190.8   267.03  136.93  532.87  114.15  144.53  456.55
        274.33  450.32  196.39  271.97  143.08  538.33  118.79  150.92  461.16
        278.84  454.92  201.25  276.58  148.7   543.26  123.17  156.41  466.08
        283.54  459.8   206.82  281.72  153.69  548.71  127.9   161.18  471.32
        289.6   465.89  215.18  289.28  162.26  557.25  135.73  170.14  478.42
        300.15  476.62  227.64  300.8   172.34  569.3   143.67  180.67  490.13
        304.18  481.02  232.49  305.13  176.67  573.65  146.77  185.03  494.78
        307.93  484.73  236.95  309.16  180.93  578.05  151.08  189.52  498.89
        314.86  491.95  245.56  317.31  188.44  587.01  157.63  196.97  506.96
        319.34  496.64  251.58  322.86  193.15  592.72  162.13  201.89  512.43
        322.94  500.21  254.97  326.17  197.98  596.44  165.82  206.1   515.86
        326.23  503.48  259.01  330.12  201.19  600.74  169.59  209.96  519.72
        335.68  512.67  269.4   340     207.87  611.07  174.25  217.11  529.81
        337.04  514.34  271.01  341.57  212.02  612.85  178.11  220.98  531.18
        344.41  522.3   280.33  350.42  219.08  622.2   184.89  228.69  539.75
        346.95  524.57  282.49  352.83  223.44  625.4   189.14  232.6   541.91
        349.62  527.56  285.37  355.45  226.67  627.7   191.43  235.5   544.78
        358.33  536.38  294.13  364.15  232.76  636.58  197.15  242.32  553.22
        358.95  537.09  295.51  365.55  235.71  637.92  199.02  244.96  554.42
        361.47  539.84  297.61  367.63  237.75  640.18  200.59  247.23  556.73
        364.33  542.6   300.56  370.38  240.59  642.86  202.72  249.89  559.45
        367.45  545.67  303.39  373.15  242.55  645.63  204.7   251.76  562.51
        373.77  552.08  310.27  380.14  250.63  652.95  213.85  259.59  569.04
        376.86  555.27  314     383.64  253.33  656.64  214.83  262.66  572.54
        380.42  558.84  317.09  386.76  255.54  659.58  216.86  265.13  575.72
        381.81  560.44  318.56  388.22  257.1   661.13  218.02  266.68  577.22
        384.37  562.96  321.13  390.91  259.19  663.82  219.89  268.72  579.7
        386.46  565.02  323.11  392.9   260.64  665.58  221.15  270.44  581.68
        389.78  568.48  325.85  395.57  263.04  668.19  221.86  272.61  584.5
        390.24  568.64  326.7   396.42  264.04  669.15  224.07  273.84  585.32
        392.9   571.55  329.13  398.93  265.58  671.4   224.83  275.18  587.9
        393.56  572.04  329.37  399.32  265.63  672.12  224.95  275.62  588.12
        393.54  572.14  329.82  399.63  265.97  672.13  225.64  275.91  588.53
        394.57  573.14  330.44  400.4   266.51  673     225.34  276.67  589.29
        395.32  573.77  331.12  401.12  266.67  673.57  225.17  276.85  590.01
        395.41  573.96  330.96  401.04  266.69  673.45  225.07  277.09  590.01
        396.03  574.45  330.97  401     266.51  673.26  224.72  276.91  590.06
        395.64  574.16  330.93  401.05  266.4   673.43  224.63  276.79  590.01
        396.9   575.27  332.04  402.01  267.36  674.8   224.66  278.04  590.71
        396.85  575.16  331.85  401.94  267.18  674.23  224.34  277.52  591.03
        396.72  574.99  331.34  401.54  266.83  673.72  224.05  277.15  590.61
        396.14  574.22  330.9   401.05  266.19  673.21  223.18  276.56  590.11
        395.57  573.84  330.09  400.28  265.4   672.2   222.31  275.74  589.46
        394.76  572.95  329.26  399.33  264.82  671.48  221.12  275.06  588.54
        394.36  572.57  328.77  399.03  264.46  671.09  220.98  274.69  588.15
        395.89  574.43  331.31  401.55  268     674.07  225.59  278.04  590.16
        396.4   574.69  331.57  401.81  267.95  674.04  224.77  278.03  590.51
        398.15  576.65  333.31  403.47  268.76  675.62  225.21  278.86  592.17
        399.66  577.98  333.85  403.82  269.77  675.91  226.11  280     593.08
        399.83  578.03  334.45  404.63  270.85  676.76  226.75  280.7   593.63
        400.14  578.4   335.19  405.5   270.94  677.38  225.97  281.17  594.11
        400.78  579.13  335.62  405.8   270.22  677.68  224.99  280.63  594.66
        400.83  578.9   335.45  405.78  270.98  677.6   225.45  281.18  594.51
        400.26  578.37  334.86  405.08  270.46  676.87  224.32  280.6   593.99
        399.94  578.27  334.33  404.5   269.53  676.04  222.84  279.71  593.56
        399.86  577.88  333.48  403.81  267.56  675.1   220.58  277.9   593.15
        400.67  578.1   334.26  404.47  268.67  676.41  221.5   279.28  593.28
        401.03  578.99  334.34  404.48  268.77  675.99  220.74  278.98  594.01
        398.93  576.6   331.81  402.19  266.24  673.27  218.07  276.49  591.52
        396.64  574.45  329.37  399.74  263.52  670.6   214.95  273.85  589.19
        394.91  572.86  328.32  398.73  262.19  669.59  212.88  272.62  587.93
        393.37  571.07  325.58  395.98  259.12  666.81  209.59  269.68  585.35
        390.63  568.11  322.44  392.85  255.98  663.51  206.31  266.57  582.64
        387.46  564.97  319.14  389.64  252.99  660.17  202.78  263.44  579.33
        384.43  561.92  315.64  386.2   249.69  656.71  199.43  260.17  576.16
        381.66  558.99  312.14  382.77  246.11  653.21  195.62  256.55  572.89
        378.16  555.32  308.35  378.95  242.47  649.12  191.52  252.8   569.3
        374.76  551.73  304.39  375.21  238.79  645.1   187.74  249.18  565.59
        370.99  548     300.8   371.77  235.28  641.78  183.73  245.6   562.16
        367.18  543.89  296.31  367.34  231.08  637.12  179.46  241.18  557.81
        364.22  540.97  293.24  364.3   228.35  633.95  176.43  238.15  554.57
        361.52  538.12  290.24  361.48  224.66  630.85  172.25  234.64  551.74
        358.19  534.75  286.59  357.88  221.74  627.08  168.77  231.56  548.3
        355.06  531.9   283.39  354.7   217.89  623.37  163.73  228.08  545.64
        352.71  528.99  280.34  351.9   215.24  620.45  160.6   224.79  542.47
        347.58  523.44  274.27  346.13  209.66  614.19  154.25  219.08  536.81
        343.21  519.24  269.22  341.08  204.59  609.05  148.46  213.96  532.08
        339.42  515.12  264.37  336.31  199.8   603.74  142.64  209.09  527.62
        334.57  510.15  259.13  331.39  194.96  598.45  136.17  203.96  522.55
        328.94  504.16  252.36  325.2   188.89  591.64  128.25  197.49  516.37
        323.63  498.83  246.88  319.83  182.93  585.93  120.67  191.93  510.75
        317.41  492.13  239.62  312.93  176.06  578.73  112.08  184.72  504.04
        311.56  486.18  232.49  306.33  169.58  571.27  102.5   177.87  497.74
        304.32  478.69  224.8   299.32  162.5   564.22  93.29   170.66  489.84
        297.07  471.14  216.81  292.08  154.89  556.54  81.96   163.03  482.16
        289.88  463.36  208.47  284.76  148.63  549.02  71.64   155.9   474.21
        283.23  456.12  199.91  276.85  140.93  541.04  60.84   148.16  465.9
        275.6   448.64  193.44  271.16  134.79  535.2   53.61   141.73  458.7
        267.38  439.75  184.53  262.97  127.11  527.08  42.53   133.74  449.84
        259.07  430.79  175.48  254.53  119.39  518.86  33.22   125.7   440.33
        251.28  422.06  167.04  246.5   111.97  511.29  25.98   118.03  431.19
        242.94  412.8   157.78  237.51  104.56  502.21  18.68   109.46  421.31
        235.05  404.05  149.17  229.59  97.36   494.35  12.16   101.8   411.72
        226.47  394.68  139.67  220.87  89.19   486.21  5.68    93.14   401.38
        219.63  386.84  132.5   213.74  82.98   479.29  0.73    86.76   393.13
        210.39  377.08  121.48  203.73  74.7    469.36  0       78.19   382.21
        202.42  368.02  111.45  194.37  66.72   460.34  0.04    70.16   371.87
        193.22  357.57  101.21  184.86  58.96   451.04  0       61.58   360.84
        184.66  347.42  91.61   175.87  51.15   442.26  0.29    53.65   350.04
        177.78  339.11  83.06   167.85  44.66   434.5   0       47.07   340.71
        169.15  329.37  74.19   158.18  35.71   425.53  0.08    38.32   330.04
        158.97  317.55  65.64   147.7   27.07   415.35  0.41    28.78   318.97
        148.86  305.77  57.43   137.07  18.36   405.18  0.79    19.38   307.7
        141.27  296.49  51.73   128.64  12.38   397.14  0       11.8    299.18
        130.93  284.4   44.99   118.8   4.7     387.55  0.05    3       288.3
        121.63  272.85  39.02   109.82  0       379.1   0.85    0       277.92
        110.87  260.19  33.21   99.41   0       369.58  0.64    0       268.08
        100.23  247.88  27.6    89.12   0       360.48  0       0       258.56
        89.88   235.5   21.87   79.18   0       351.66  0.07    0       249.61
        79.48   223.11  16.13   69.72   0       343.38  0.93    0       241.4
        69.36   210.96  10.59   60.31   0       334.81  0.68    0       233.89
        59.52   199.03  5.3     51.51   0       326.7   0.66    0       227.22
        50.43   188.16  0       42.78   0       318.46  0.96    0       222.01
        41.5    176.75  0       34.36   0       310.55  0.77    0       216.3
        33.06   166.26  0       26.21   0       302.72  2.45    0       211.19
        27.62   158.94  0.11    20.34   0       296.99  1.39    0.49    208.83
        21.79   152.06  0       14.22   0       291.45  1       0       207.02
        13.44   141.59  0.56    6.55    0       284.3   0.96    0       202.11
        8.48    131.81  0.86    2.24    0       276.05  0.96    0       197.55
        5.18    121.56  0.43    0.22    0       267.24  0.69    0       193.19
        5.55    112.7   1.83    2.65    0       258.93  0.93    0.05    189.85
        2.75    101.37  1.41    1.07    0       249.63  0.83    0.21    184.96
        0.34    89.76   1.51    1.52    0       239.76  1.09    0.39    179.2
        0       78.12   1.62    1.03    0       229.76  1.03    0       171.69
        0       65.92   1.98    1.29    0.28    219.02  1.01    0.44    163.7
        0       53.23   2.02    3.02    0.2     207.3   1.09    0.48    155.3
        0.59    39.72   1.87    1.99    0       194.49  0.92    0.58    146.41
        0.88    26.09   2.02    2.44    0       180.87  1.1     0.73    136.95
        0.85    12.84   2.07    3.18    0       168.11  0.92    0.68    128.04
        0.99    1.34    2.16    3.16    0       155.92  0.93    0.84    119.01
        0.79    1.35    2.05    3.72    0       141.77  0.83    0.5     108.4
        0.93    1.43    2.09    3.68    0       128.36  0.93    0.2     97.73
        2.02    1.77    2.23    3       0       113.46  1.16    0.7     90.26
        0.94    1.52    2.03    2.76    0       97.74   0.87    0.33    78.67
        0.76    1.4     2.01    2.31    0       81.79   1.08    0.33    66.81
        0.73    1.52    1.83    3.63    0       64.1    0.85    0.52    54.76
        0.72    1.3     1.92    3.16    0       46.5    0.96    0.52    42.52
        0.92    1.43    1.89    3.09    0.04    27.81   1.09    0.56    30.09
        0.88    1.48    1.88    3.16    0       8.53    0.91    0.57    16.79
        0.68    1.35    1.95    3.05    0       0       0.94    0.37    3.03
        0.79    1.38    2.15    3.28    0       0.72    0.97    0.27    0
        0.99    1.45    2.33    2.89    0       1.48    0.98    0.37    0
        0.6     1.2     2.01    3.35    0       1.18    1.17    0.45    0.43
        0.68    1.39    2.12    3.32    0.12    1.35    0.9     0.6     1.09
        0.93    1.56    2.11    4.33    0       1.4     1.08    0.34    1.09
        0.97    1.47    2.05    3.2     0       1.38    1.08    0.44    1.77
        0.73    1.3     1.9     3.94    0       1.41    1.2     0.61    1.06
        0.69    1.36    1.96    3.21    0.06    1.23    1.21    0.53    1.05
        0.81    1.39    2.18    4.35    0       1.3     0.97    0.34    1.13
        0.8     1.38    2.02    3.26    0       1.26    1.07    0.4     1.02
        0.52    1.26    1.98    3.41    0.07    1.4     1.56    0.35    1.04
        1.17    1.81    2.54    3.62    0       1.32    0.86    1.53    1.16
        0.65    1.32    2.02    3.81    0       1.29    0.92    0.75    1.05
        0.79    1.36    1.94    3.54    0.06    1.34    0.99    0.56    1.14
        0.72    1.46    2.01    3.96    0       1.38    1.02    0.37    1.15
        0.69    1.33    1.88    3.01    0       1.25    0.99    0.42    1.06
        1.23    1.87    1.9     3.97    0       1.26    1.37    0.58    1.07
        0.7     1.28    2.14    3.53    0.11    1.76    1       1.51    1.1
        0.69    1.32    2.07    3.45    0       1.34    0.96    0.31    1.14
        1.32    1.74    1.89    3.28    0       1.24    1.17    0.35    1.01
        0.79    1.42    2.12    3.49    0       1.47    0.98    0.3     1.08
        0.82    1.29    2.03    3.23    0       1.39    1.07    0.31    1.06
        0.76    1.43    2.26    3.94    0.09    1.67    0.86    0.85    1.06
        0.73    1.37    2.22    4.05    0       1.53    0.91    1.33    1.09
        0.98    1.55    2.18    4.87    0       1.47    1.32    1.89    1.08
        0.77    1.51    2.11    4.14    0       1.33    0.94    0.46    1.08
        0.91    1.37    2.07    3.28    0       1.37    1.37    0.67    1.04
        0.81    1.42    2.02    3.24    0.01    1.25    1.28    0.82    1.03
        0.76    1.47    2.04    3.4     0       1.48    1.27    2       1.07
        0.63    1.24    2.1     3.37    0.01    1.28    0.82    1       1.06
        0.65    1.31    2.16    4.41    0       1.37    1.48    1.87    1.08
        0.47    1.22    1.94    3.15    0.12    1.19    1.15    0.8     0.97
        0.6     1.35    1.95    3.25    0       1.34    1.02    0.29    1.07
        0.7     1.41    1.98    4.06    0       1.18    1.26    0.29    1.08
        0.67    1.36    1.95    3.69    0       1.28    1.07    0.48    1.05
        0.67    1.32    1.92    3.13    0       1.26    1.16    0.4     1
        0.88    1.58    1.93    4.33    0       1.33    1.8     1.78    2.56
        0.68    1.4     2.05    3.39    0       1.35    1.21    0.63    0.94
        0.7     1.88    1.95    3.23    0       1.19    1.41    0.47    0.98
        0.63    1.28    1.84    3.19    0       1.2     1.02    0.4     1.06
        0.55    1.25    1.61    2.95    0.13    1.06    1.22    0.57    0.95
        0.82    1.49    1.61    2.88    0       1.11    1.17    0.34    1.16
        0.7     1.45    1.93    3.32    0       1.27    1.02    0.32    1.12
        0.68    1.3     1.88    3.15    0       1.1     0.98    0.35    0.93
        0.53    1.28    1.79    3.04    0       1.32    0.92    0.38    0.92
        0.73    1.41    1.8     3.08    0       1.27    1.22    0.59    0.96
        0.64    1.37    1.98    3.48    0       1.38    1.77    1.9     1.08
        0.76    1.38    2       2.51    0       1.37    1.04    1.49    1.13

    }\dummydata
    \begin{axis}[
    domain=32:311,
    samples y=0, ytick={1,...,3,5,...,10},
    zmin=0,
    area plot/.style={
        fill opacity=0.75,
        draw=orange!80!black,thick,
        fill=orange,
        mark=none,
    }
    ]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{10,9,...,5,3,...,1}{
        \addplot3 [area plot] table [x expr=\coordindex, y expr=#1, z=logger#1]
        {\dummydata};
    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I'm not entirely sure what kind of axis labels you're going for. I'm going to assume that the data from your loggers starts at `x=32`. Using `x expr=\coordindex` will make the data start at `0`, however. Change that to `x expr=\coordindex+32` to shift the data, and set `xmin=32, xmax=311` to adjust the axis limits.
2. I assume you mean "Y labels", not "Z labels". I also assume that your Y axis uses an ordinal scale (or, more correctly, a nominal one, since the numbers are really just labels). In that case, you don't want the gap between the data from loggers 3 and 5 to be larger than that between loggers 5 and 6. For that you'll need to use `y expr=8-\numplots` instead of `y expr=#1`, and to set `yticklabels={1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10}` to explicitly define the values of the tick labels.
3. To fix this, you'll need to split each plot into two: one for the upper boundary of the surfaces, and one for the surfaces. This means that you'll need to use `y expr=8-\numplots/2` for the line plots and `y expr=8.5-\numplots/2` for the area plots. To close the surfaces, you can add `-- (axis cs:\pgfplots@data@xmax,8.5-\plotnum/2,0) -- (axis cs:\pgfplots@data@xmin,8.5-\plotnum/2,0)` at the end of the `\addplot` command. For this to work, you'll also need to add `\makeatletter` before `\begin{tikzpicture}`.
4. I can't think of an elegant way to do this without preprocessing the data.
5. You can use a `plot cycle list` in combination with `\addplot +[<...>]` instead of `\addplot [<...>]` for this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread{
        logger1 logger2 logger3 logger5 logger6 logger7 logger8 logger9 logger10
        1.04    33.89   2.3     3.19    0.01    134.57  0.58    0.2     99.5
        1.04    39.82   2.48    4.22    0       142.46  0.5     0.14    105.36
        1.04    46.34   2.38    2.61    0.27    145.42  0.71    0.61    109.83
        1.06    48.67   2.35    3.21    0.23    148.91  0.52    0.48    113.52
        1.15    52.63   2.31    3.26    0.03    152.23  0.72    0.27    118.07
        1.19    57.98   2.32    3.19    0       156.89  0.46    0.25    124
        1.02    59.51   2.39    3.24    0.15    158.96  0.35    0.25    125.97
        1.01    62.61   2.38    3.27    0.16    161.51  0.59    0.3     128.89
        1.07    64.75   2.4     3.17    0.18    162.86  0.78    0.46    130.14
        1.09    66.48   2.35    3.23    0.01    164.62  0.56    0.28    131.55
        1.21    69.16   2.35    3.24    0.04    167.08  0.57    0.28    134.21
        1.12    70.52   2.36    3.25    0       167.92  0.42    0.1     134.95
        1.21    72.26   2.39    3.98    0.12    171.72  0.71    0.4     139.06
        0.99    74.29   2.33    3.35    0.04    175.4   0.58    0.28    141.23
        0.98    75.08   2.3     3.06    0.07    175.79  0.4     0.53    141.31
        0.97    75.31   2.23    3.1     0.05    176.28  0.35    0.33    141.42
        0.94    74.85   2.2     2.99    0.04    176.01  0.44    0.24    141.35
        1       75.06   2.33    3.22    0.38    176.6   0.78    0.79    142.13
        1.04    75.46   2.24    3.11    0.23    176.59  0.58    0.45    141.92
        1.13    75.91   2.24    3.17    0.37    176.35  0.49    0.52    142.57
        1.07    75.17   2.13    2.93    0.18    175.35  0.52    0.37    141.51
        1.1     75.16   2.23    3.12    0.36    174.8   0.4     0.37    140.83
        1.14    77.29   2.35    3.3     0.27    175.37  0.65    0.55    141.93
        1.03    75.24   2.46    3.31    0       175.2   0.48    0.34    142.02
        1.2     78.83   2.19    3.09    0.18    175.81  0.54    0.4     142.99
        0.95    81.1    2.43    4.03    0.2     179.43  0.38    0.37    146.77
        1.1     81.94   2.41    3.26    0.07    180.02  0.49    0.5     146.72
        1.07    82.88   2.33    3.18    0.03    180.69  0.47    0.24    146.95
        1.1     89.25   2.35    3.2     0.07    187.26  0.55    0.32    151.91
        1.01    90.72   2.45    3.25    0.22    187.8   0.48    0.29    152.95
        1.05    93.72   2.32    3.48    0.18    190.84  0.66    0.31    155.68
        10.09   103.3   2.52    4.38    0.06    196.2   0.46    0.36    161.86
        6.41    105.08  2.42    2.99    0       197.89  1.01    0.25    163.24
        7.48    109.4   2.35    3.66    0.01    202.16  0.84    0.28    167.59
        7.09    116.85  2.44    3.99    0.05    210.24  0.47    0.8     171.93
        4.93    120.31  2.53    2.8     0.06    213.24  0.44    0.34    173.9
        2.44    122.82  2.53    3.32    0.03    216.29  0.53    0.23    175.44
        0.48    124.8   2.33    3.19    0.07    217.75  0.83    0.37    177.02
        0.98    127.75  2.49    3.43    0.06    222.64  0.55    0.39    179.72
        1.17    130.53  2.35    3.18    0.05    224.79  0.56    0.29    181.21
        1.04    133.33  2.21    3.7     0       228     0.66    0.48    182.96
        1.09    136.93  2.32    3.04    0.07    231.08  0.46    0.44    185.99
        1.08    139.51  2.42    2.87    0       233.2   0.41    0.13    186.95
        1.12    142.39  2.24    3.11    0       236.51  0.68    0.27    188.07
        0.96    145.84  2.15    3       0.07    239.89  0.72    0.34    189.44
        7.26    150.55  2.26    3.13    0       244.91  0.76    0.15    193.05
        19      156.77  2.3     3.62    0.13    252.07  1.09    0.49    196.24
        24.76   162.59  2.27    7.59    0.28    256.2   0.16    0.23    198.43
        30.8    169.09  2.42    12.26   0.07    261.25  0.46    0.65    200.97
        36.49   175.78  2.16    19.28   0       268.86  0.39    0.6     205.38
        46.56   187     2.56    31.82   0       281.19  0.4     1.15    213.23
        52.32   192.39  2.54    36.27   0       284.88  0.48    0.25    213.33
        60.69   200.95  2.51    44.46   0       293.09  0.63    0.42    216.23
        66.62   206.93  2.19    49.6    0.1     298.31  0.68    0.5     216.95
        76.83   217.2   2.28    59.9    0.08    309.94  0.59    0.38    221.61
        83.8    224.78  2.42    66.16   0       315.07  0.42    0.18    224.75
        89.88   231.06  2.31    71.7    0.05    320.66  0.65    0.31    228.32
        95.05   236.6   2.21    76.46   0.06    325.77  0.65    0.48    232.09
        100.91  242.75  6.13    81.6    0.06    331.23  0.68    0.46    237.2
        105.79  247.85  9.7     86.78   0.04    337.07  0.52    0.25    241.83
        111.07  253.96  13.96   91.13   0.09    342.27  0.76    0.46    248.13
        115.87  259.16  17.23   95.22   0.12    347.03  0.85    0.65    252.64
        121.45  265.19  20.33   100.34  0.34    353.11  0.78    0.47    257.69
        124.94  269.96  23.12   104.2   0.13    357.55  0.79    0.5     262.48
        132.65  277.22  26.44   110.57  1.58    364.74  1.09    0.17    268.7
        139.83  284.11  30.18   115.76  7.07    371.3   1.04    2.04    274.64
        143.19  291.74  35.54   121.89  9.22    379.72  0.6     0.39    283.49
        147.56  297.5   39.42   126.47  15.37   385.13  0.68    4.28    289.41
        152.5   303.81  43.2    131.42  19.48   391.04  0.69    10.7    295.63
        156.07  308.78  47.41   135.41  23.36   396.29  3.74    15.49   301.23
        160.26  314.27  51.31   139.93  26.62   401.58  6.57    20.08   307.05
        165.22  321.46  56.01   145.29  29.61   407.4   9.83    23.81   314.71
        169.3   326.5   60.22   150.31  33.48   412.99  15.54   30.42   320.69
        173.4   331.8   65.78   154.57  38.48   418.08  18.84   35.76   326.14
        176.62  336.59  70.23   158.28  41.41   422.38  22.09   39.18   331.57
        180.56  341.49  75.32   162.76  45.36   427.49  25.74   44.47   337.27
        185.19  348.33  82.82   167.88  47.89   433.3   29.25   49.51   345.45
        189.16  353.51  86.51   172.41  51.18   438.09  33.51   51.94   350.32
        192.3   356.9   90.2    175.23  54.97   440.71  36.66   56.42   354.57
        197.07  362.8   95.19   181.59  60.2    447.24  44.88   61.4    360.87
        200.26  367.21  100.86  184.61  63.27   450.31  45.54   66.13   366.12
        206.44  374.39  108.42  192.36  68.55   458.13  53.1    72      374.58
        211     380.06  114.94  196.98  74.34   462.88  56.56   78.03   380.93
        218.52  388.48  122.12  204.86  78.96   470.05  60.99   83.15   389.71
        222.6   393.14  130.06  210.16  85.74   475.87  67.26   90.15   396.27
        229.26  401.11  138.22  217.3   91.92   482.86  72.75   96.93   405.35
        233.61  406.03  145.25  222.65  96.74   488.17  76.88   102.73  411.29
        238.74  410.74  150.47  227.68  102.14  493.35  81.5    107.96  416.78
        242.82  416.43  157.08  234.1   108.93  500.07  87.9    114.92  423.07
        248.89  422.84  165.3   242.24  115.27  507.92  93.92   122.05  430.88
        253.41  428.29  170.38  246.97  120.23  512.91  98.2    126.97  436.32
        260.5   435.37  178.81  255.85  126.99  522.15  104.62  134.18  444.96
        270.44  446.25  190.8   267.03  136.93  532.87  114.15  144.53  456.55
        274.33  450.32  196.39  271.97  143.08  538.33  118.79  150.92  461.16
        278.84  454.92  201.25  276.58  148.7   543.26  123.17  156.41  466.08
        283.54  459.8   206.82  281.72  153.69  548.71  127.9   161.18  471.32
        289.6   465.89  215.18  289.28  162.26  557.25  135.73  170.14  478.42
        300.15  476.62  227.64  300.8   172.34  569.3   143.67  180.67  490.13
        304.18  481.02  232.49  305.13  176.67  573.65  146.77  185.03  494.78
        307.93  484.73  236.95  309.16  180.93  578.05  151.08  189.52  498.89
        314.86  491.95  245.56  317.31  188.44  587.01  157.63  196.97  506.96
        319.34  496.64  251.58  322.86  193.15  592.72  162.13  201.89  512.43
        322.94  500.21  254.97  326.17  197.98  596.44  165.82  206.1   515.86
        326.23  503.48  259.01  330.12  201.19  600.74  169.59  209.96  519.72
        335.68  512.67  269.4   340     207.87  611.07  174.25  217.11  529.81
        337.04  514.34  271.01  341.57  212.02  612.85  178.11  220.98  531.18
        344.41  522.3   280.33  350.42  219.08  622.2   184.89  228.69  539.75
        346.95  524.57  282.49  352.83  223.44  625.4   189.14  232.6   541.91
        349.62  527.56  285.37  355.45  226.67  627.7   191.43  235.5   544.78
        358.33  536.38  294.13  364.15  232.76  636.58  197.15  242.32  553.22
        358.95  537.09  295.51  365.55  235.71  637.92  199.02  244.96  554.42
        361.47  539.84  297.61  367.63  237.75  640.18  200.59  247.23  556.73
        364.33  542.6   300.56  370.38  240.59  642.86  202.72  249.89  559.45
        367.45  545.67  303.39  373.15  242.55  645.63  204.7   251.76  562.51
        373.77  552.08  310.27  380.14  250.63  652.95  213.85  259.59  569.04
        376.86  555.27  314     383.64  253.33  656.64  214.83  262.66  572.54
        380.42  558.84  317.09  386.76  255.54  659.58  216.86  265.13  575.72
        381.81  560.44  318.56  388.22  257.1   661.13  218.02  266.68  577.22
        384.37  562.96  321.13  390.91  259.19  663.82  219.89  268.72  579.7
        386.46  565.02  323.11  392.9   260.64  665.58  221.15  270.44  581.68
        389.78  568.48  325.85  395.57  263.04  668.19  221.86  272.61  584.5
        390.24  568.64  326.7   396.42  264.04  669.15  224.07  273.84  585.32
        392.9   571.55  329.13  398.93  265.58  671.4   224.83  275.18  587.9
        393.56  572.04  329.37  399.32  265.63  672.12  224.95  275.62  588.12
        393.54  572.14  329.82  399.63  265.97  672.13  225.64  275.91  588.53
        394.57  573.14  330.44  400.4   266.51  673     225.34  276.67  589.29
        395.32  573.77  331.12  401.12  266.67  673.57  225.17  276.85  590.01
        395.41  573.96  330.96  401.04  266.69  673.45  225.07  277.09  590.01
        396.03  574.45  330.97  401     266.51  673.26  224.72  276.91  590.06
        395.64  574.16  330.93  401.05  266.4   673.43  224.63  276.79  590.01
        396.9   575.27  332.04  402.01  267.36  674.8   224.66  278.04  590.71
        396.85  575.16  331.85  401.94  267.18  674.23  224.34  277.52  591.03
        396.72  574.99  331.34  401.54  266.83  673.72  224.05  277.15  590.61
        396.14  574.22  330.9   401.05  266.19  673.21  223.18  276.56  590.11
        395.57  573.84  330.09  400.28  265.4   672.2   222.31  275.74  589.46
        394.76  572.95  329.26  399.33  264.82  671.48  221.12  275.06  588.54
        394.36  572.57  328.77  399.03  264.46  671.09  220.98  274.69  588.15
        395.89  574.43  331.31  401.55  268     674.07  225.59  278.04  590.16
        396.4   574.69  331.57  401.81  267.95  674.04  224.77  278.03  590.51
        398.15  576.65  333.31  403.47  268.76  675.62  225.21  278.86  592.17
        399.66  577.98  333.85  403.82  269.77  675.91  226.11  280     593.08
        399.83  578.03  334.45  404.63  270.85  676.76  226.75  280.7   593.63
        400.14  578.4   335.19  405.5   270.94  677.38  225.97  281.17  594.11
        400.78  579.13  335.62  405.8   270.22  677.68  224.99  280.63  594.66
        400.83  578.9   335.45  405.78  270.98  677.6   225.45  281.18  594.51
        400.26  578.37  334.86  405.08  270.46  676.87  224.32  280.6   593.99
        399.94  578.27  334.33  404.5   269.53  676.04  222.84  279.71  593.56
        399.86  577.88  333.48  403.81  267.56  675.1   220.58  277.9   593.15
        400.67  578.1   334.26  404.47  268.67  676.41  221.5   279.28  593.28
        401.03  578.99  334.34  404.48  268.77  675.99  220.74  278.98  594.01
        398.93  576.6   331.81  402.19  266.24  673.27  218.07  276.49  591.52
        396.64  574.45  329.37  399.74  263.52  670.6   214.95  273.85  589.19
        394.91  572.86  328.32  398.73  262.19  669.59  212.88  272.62  587.93
        393.37  571.07  325.58  395.98  259.12  666.81  209.59  269.68  585.35
        390.63  568.11  322.44  392.85  255.98  663.51  206.31  266.57  582.64
        387.46  564.97  319.14  389.64  252.99  660.17  202.78  263.44  579.33
        384.43  561.92  315.64  386.2   249.69  656.71  199.43  260.17  576.16
        381.66  558.99  312.14  382.77  246.11  653.21  195.62  256.55  572.89
        378.16  555.32  308.35  378.95  242.47  649.12  191.52  252.8   569.3
        374.76  551.73  304.39  375.21  238.79  645.1   187.74  249.18  565.59
        370.99  548     300.8   371.77  235.28  641.78  183.73  245.6   562.16
        367.18  543.89  296.31  367.34  231.08  637.12  179.46  241.18  557.81
        364.22  540.97  293.24  364.3   228.35  633.95  176.43  238.15  554.57
        361.52  538.12  290.24  361.48  224.66  630.85  172.25  234.64  551.74
        358.19  534.75  286.59  357.88  221.74  627.08  168.77  231.56  548.3
        355.06  531.9   283.39  354.7   217.89  623.37  163.73  228.08  545.64
        352.71  528.99  280.34  351.9   215.24  620.45  160.6   224.79  542.47
        347.58  523.44  274.27  346.13  209.66  614.19  154.25  219.08  536.81
        343.21  519.24  269.22  341.08  204.59  609.05  148.46  213.96  532.08
        339.42  515.12  264.37  336.31  199.8   603.74  142.64  209.09  527.62
        334.57  510.15  259.13  331.39  194.96  598.45  136.17  203.96  522.55
        328.94  504.16  252.36  325.2   188.89  591.64  128.25  197.49  516.37
        323.63  498.83  246.88  319.83  182.93  585.93  120.67  191.93  510.75
        317.41  492.13  239.62  312.93  176.06  578.73  112.08  184.72  504.04
        311.56  486.18  232.49  306.33  169.58  571.27  102.5   177.87  497.74
        304.32  478.69  224.8   299.32  162.5   564.22  93.29   170.66  489.84
        297.07  471.14  216.81  292.08  154.89  556.54  81.96   163.03  482.16
        289.88  463.36  208.47  284.76  148.63  549.02  71.64   155.9   474.21
        283.23  456.12  199.91  276.85  140.93  541.04  60.84   148.16  465.9
        275.6   448.64  193.44  271.16  134.79  535.2   53.61   141.73  458.7
        267.38  439.75  184.53  262.97  127.11  527.08  42.53   133.74  449.84
        259.07  430.79  175.48  254.53  119.39  518.86  33.22   125.7   440.33
        251.28  422.06  167.04  246.5   111.97  511.29  25.98   118.03  431.19
        242.94  412.8   157.78  237.51  104.56  502.21  18.68   109.46  421.31
        235.05  404.05  149.17  229.59  97.36   494.35  12.16   101.8   411.72
        226.47  394.68  139.67  220.87  89.19   486.21  5.68    93.14   401.38
        219.63  386.84  132.5   213.74  82.98   479.29  0.73    86.76   393.13
        210.39  377.08  121.48  203.73  74.7    469.36  0       78.19   382.21
        202.42  368.02  111.45  194.37  66.72   460.34  0.04    70.16   371.87
        193.22  357.57  101.21  184.86  58.96   451.04  0       61.58   360.84
        184.66  347.42  91.61   175.87  51.15   442.26  0.29    53.65   350.04
        177.78  339.11  83.06   167.85  44.66   434.5   0       47.07   340.71
        169.15  329.37  74.19   158.18  35.71   425.53  0.08    38.32   330.04
        158.97  317.55  65.64   147.7   27.07   415.35  0.41    28.78   318.97
        148.86  305.77  57.43   137.07  18.36   405.18  0.79    19.38   307.7
        141.27  296.49  51.73   128.64  12.38   397.14  0       11.8    299.18
        130.93  284.4   44.99   118.8   4.7     387.55  0.05    3       288.3
        121.63  272.85  39.02   109.82  0       379.1   0.85    0       277.92
        110.87  260.19  33.21   99.41   0       369.58  0.64    0       268.08
        100.23  247.88  27.6    89.12   0       360.48  0       0       258.56
        89.88   235.5   21.87   79.18   0       351.66  0.07    0       249.61
        79.48   223.11  16.13   69.72   0       343.38  0.93    0       241.4
        69.36   210.96  10.59   60.31   0       334.81  0.68    0       233.89
        59.52   199.03  5.3     51.51   0       326.7   0.66    0       227.22
        50.43   188.16  0       42.78   0       318.46  0.96    0       222.01
        41.5    176.75  0       34.36   0       310.55  0.77    0       216.3
        33.06   166.26  0       26.21   0       302.72  2.45    0       211.19
        27.62   158.94  0.11    20.34   0       296.99  1.39    0.49    208.83
        21.79   152.06  0       14.22   0       291.45  1       0       207.02
        13.44   141.59  0.56    6.55    0       284.3   0.96    0       202.11
        8.48    131.81  0.86    2.24    0       276.05  0.96    0       197.55
        5.18    121.56  0.43    0.22    0       267.24  0.69    0       193.19
        5.55    112.7   1.83    2.65    0       258.93  0.93    0.05    189.85
        2.75    101.37  1.41    1.07    0       249.63  0.83    0.21    184.96
        0.34    89.76   1.51    1.52    0       239.76  1.09    0.39    179.2
        0       78.12   1.62    1.03    0       229.76  1.03    0       171.69
        0       65.92   1.98    1.29    0.28    219.02  1.01    0.44    163.7
        0       53.23   2.02    3.02    0.2     207.3   1.09    0.48    155.3
        0.59    39.72   1.87    1.99    0       194.49  0.92    0.58    146.41
        0.88    26.09   2.02    2.44    0       180.87  1.1     0.73    136.95
        0.85    12.84   2.07    3.18    0       168.11  0.92    0.68    128.04
        0.99    1.34    2.16    3.16    0       155.92  0.93    0.84    119.01
        0.79    1.35    2.05    3.72    0       141.77  0.83    0.5     108.4
        0.93    1.43    2.09    3.68    0       128.36  0.93    0.2     97.73
        2.02    1.77    2.23    3       0       113.46  1.16    0.7     90.26
        0.94    1.52    2.03    2.76    0       97.74   0.87    0.33    78.67
        0.76    1.4     2.01    2.31    0       81.79   1.08    0.33    66.81
        0.73    1.52    1.83    3.63    0       64.1    0.85    0.52    54.76
        0.72    1.3     1.92    3.16    0       46.5    0.96    0.52    42.52
        0.92    1.43    1.89    3.09    0.04    27.81   1.09    0.56    30.09
        0.88    1.48    1.88    3.16    0       8.53    0.91    0.57    16.79
        0.68    1.35    1.95    3.05    0       0       0.94    0.37    3.03
        0.79    1.38    2.15    3.28    0       0.72    0.97    0.27    0
        0.99    1.45    2.33    2.89    0       1.48    0.98    0.37    0
        0.6     1.2     2.01    3.35    0       1.18    1.17    0.45    0.43
        0.68    1.39    2.12    3.32    0.12    1.35    0.9     0.6     1.09
        0.93    1.56    2.11    4.33    0       1.4     1.08    0.34    1.09
        0.97    1.47    2.05    3.2     0       1.38    1.08    0.44    1.77
        0.73    1.3     1.9     3.94    0       1.41    1.2     0.61    1.06
        0.69    1.36    1.96    3.21    0.06    1.23    1.21    0.53    1.05
        0.81    1.39    2.18    4.35    0       1.3     0.97    0.34    1.13
        0.8     1.38    2.02    3.26    0       1.26    1.07    0.4     1.02
        0.52    1.26    1.98    3.41    0.07    1.4     1.56    0.35    1.04
        1.17    1.81    2.54    3.62    0       1.32    0.86    1.53    1.16
        0.65    1.32    2.02    3.81    0       1.29    0.92    0.75    1.05
        0.79    1.36    1.94    3.54    0.06    1.34    0.99    0.56    1.14
        0.72    1.46    2.01    3.96    0       1.38    1.02    0.37    1.15
        0.69    1.33    1.88    3.01    0       1.25    0.99    0.42    1.06
        1.23    1.87    1.9     3.97    0       1.26    1.37    0.58    1.07
        0.7     1.28    2.14    3.53    0.11    1.76    1       1.51    1.1
        0.69    1.32    2.07    3.45    0       1.34    0.96    0.31    1.14
        1.32    1.74    1.89    3.28    0       1.24    1.17    0.35    1.01
        0.79    1.42    2.12    3.49    0       1.47    0.98    0.3     1.08
        0.82    1.29    2.03    3.23    0       1.39    1.07    0.31    1.06
        0.76    1.43    2.26    3.94    0.09    1.67    0.86    0.85    1.06
        0.73    1.37    2.22    4.05    0       1.53    0.91    1.33    1.09
        0.98    1.55    2.18    4.87    0       1.47    1.32    1.89    1.08
        0.77    1.51    2.11    4.14    0       1.33    0.94    0.46    1.08
        0.91    1.37    2.07    3.28    0       1.37    1.37    0.67    1.04
        0.81    1.42    2.02    3.24    0.01    1.25    1.28    0.82    1.03
        0.76    1.47    2.04    3.4     0       1.48    1.27    2       1.07
        0.63    1.24    2.1     3.37    0.01    1.28    0.82    1       1.06
        0.65    1.31    2.16    4.41    0       1.37    1.48    1.87    1.08
        0.47    1.22    1.94    3.15    0.12    1.19    1.15    0.8     0.97
        0.6     1.35    1.95    3.25    0       1.34    1.02    0.29    1.07
        0.7     1.41    1.98    4.06    0       1.18    1.26    0.29    1.08
        0.67    1.36    1.95    3.69    0       1.28    1.07    0.48    1.05
        0.67    1.32    1.92    3.13    0       1.26    1.16    0.4     1
        0.88    1.58    1.93    4.33    0       1.33    1.8     1.78    2.56
        0.68    1.4     2.05    3.39    0       1.35    1.21    0.63    0.94
        0.7     1.88    1.95    3.23    0       1.19    1.41    0.47    0.98
        0.63    1.28    1.84    3.19    0       1.2     1.02    0.4     1.06
        0.55    1.25    1.61    2.95    0.13    1.06    1.22    0.57    0.95
        0.82    1.49    1.61    2.88    0       1.11    1.17    0.34    1.16
        0.7     1.45    1.93    3.32    0       1.27    1.02    0.32    1.12
        0.68    1.3     1.88    3.15    0       1.1     0.98    0.35    0.93
        0.53    1.28    1.79    3.04    0       1.32    0.92    0.38    0.92
        0.73    1.41    1.8     3.08    0       1.27    1.22    0.59    0.96
        0.64    1.37    1.98    3.48    0       1.38    1.77    1.9     1.08
        0.76    1.38    2       2.51    0       1.37    1.04    1.49    1.13

    }\dummydata
    \begin{axis}[
    xmin=32, xmax=311,
    ymin=0, ymax=9,
    ytick={0,...,10},
    yticklabels={1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10},
    zmin=0,
    area plot/.style={
        fill opacity=0.75,
        fill=orange,
        mark=none,
        draw=none
    },
    line plot/.style={
        draw=orange!80!black,thick
    }
    ]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{10,9,...,5,3,2,1}{
        \addplot3 [line plot] table [x expr=\coordindex+32, y expr=8-\numplots/2, z=logger#1]
        {\dummydata};
        \addplot3 [area plot] table [x expr=\coordindex+32, y expr=8.5-\numplots/2, z=logger#1]
        {\dummydata} -- (axis cs:\pgfplots@data@xmax,8.5-\plotnum/2,0) -- (axis cs:\pgfplots@data@xmin,8.5-\plotnum/2,0);
    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice Jake, it worked like a charm. Thank you